# Google test framework parametrize fixtures

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

i have a one question. i use the following structure as fixture:

```
class unvalidSDPTest : public ::testing::Test{
protected:
    virtual void SetUp(){
        std::string Name("name");
        Server=new SipServer(Name);
        std::ifstream offerFile,answerFile;
        offerFile.open("unvalidOfferSDP.txt");
        answerFile.open("unvalidAnswerSDP.txt");
        std::string offerRawSDP,answerRawSDP;
        offerFile>>offerRawSDP;
        answerFile>>answerRawSDP;
        offerSDPSession = Server->MakeSDPSession( const_cast(offerRawSDP.c_str()) ) ;
        answerSDPSession = Server->MakeSDPSession( const_cast(answerRawSDP.c_str()) ) ;
    }
    virtual void TearDown(){
        delete Server;
    }
    pjmedia_sdp_session *offerSDPSession, *answerSDPSession ;
    SipServer *Server;
    SDPNeg Negotiator;
};
```

and i want to parametrize this class by file name. how make it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways to do this - I'll show you two:

Method 1: Create a base class with a virtual functions, then derive from it.

```
class unvalidSDPTestBase : public ::testing::Test{
  virtual const char * offer_filename() const =0;
  virtual const char * answer_filename() const =0;
  protected:
    virtual void SetUp(){
        std::string Name("name");
        Server=new SipServer(Name);
        std::ifstream offerFile,answerFile;
        offerFile.open( offer_filename());
        answerFile.open(answer_filename());
        std::string offerRawSDP,answerRawSDP;
        offerFile>>offerRawSDP;
        answerFile>>answerRawSDP;
        offerSDPSession = Server->MakeSDPSession( const_cast(offerRawSDP.c_str()) ) ;
        answerSDPSession = Server->MakeSDPSession( const_cast(answerRawSDP.c_str()) ) ;
    }
    virtual void TearDown(){
        delete Server;
    }
    pjmedia_sdp_session *offerSDPSession, *answerSDPSession ;
    SipServer *Server;
    SDPNeg Negotiator;
 };

 class unvalidSPDTestBase: public unvalidSDPTestBase
 {
     virtual const char * offer_filename() const { return "..."; }
     virtual const char * answer_filename() const { return "..."; }
 }
```

Method 2: use a traits like system and templating:

```
template<typename FILENAME_SOURCE>
class SDPTest : public ::testing::Test{
  protected:
    virtual void SetUp(){
        std::string Name("name");
        Server=new SipServer(Name);
        std::ifstream offerFile,answerFile;
        offerFile.open( FILENAME_SOURCE::offer_filename());
        answerFile.open( FILENAME_SOURCE::answer_filename());
        std::string offerRawSDP,answerRawSDP;
        offerFile>>offerRawSDP;
        answerFile>>answerRawSDP;
        offerSDPSession = Server->MakeSDPSession( const_cast(offerRawSDP.c_str()) ) ;
        answerSDPSession = Server->MakeSDPSession( const_cast(answerRawSDP.c_str()) ) ;
    }
    virtual void TearDown(){
        delete Server;
    }
    pjmedia_sdp_session *offerSDPSession, *answerSDPSession ;
    SipServer *Server;
    SDPNeg Negotiator;
 };

 struct InvalidFilenames
 {
   static const char * offer_filename()  { return "..."; }
   static const char * answer_filename() { return "..."; }
 };

 typedef SDPTest<InvalidFilenames> unvalidSDPTest;
```